# How to change the font color of title, author, date and make it bold in yaml of Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

```
---
title: "PDF Document"
author: "Sana"
date: "27-05-2022"
---
```

How to change the font color and style of title, author, date and make it bold or italic in yaml of Rmarkdown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use a latex code chunk in the title.

````
---
title: |
  ```{=latex}
  \textcolor{red}{\textbf{PDF Document}}
  ```
author: "Sana"
output: pdf_document
---
````